# To display json on web browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

We want to display json of Google search results on browser called from servlet using Google API. The `handleSearchResult` is not displaying the responseText on browser. 
Also the servlet is not mapping the querywords from the text box of html to Google API search url(servlet). Thanks

home.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var request;

function handleSearchResult(){
    alert("hanldeRes");
    //query.text = resp.items.name;
    alert(request.responseText);
    //var resp = eval('('+responseText+')');
    //alert(resp.items.title);  
}

function createHttpRequest()
{
    alert("insideCreateRequest");
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    } 
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)   {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

        if(!request) {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    if(request) {
        request.onreadystatechange = handleSearchResult();
        request.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/WebSearchOptimization/SearchService",true);
        request.send(null);

    } 
    else {
        alert("error on Page createHttpRequest");
    }
    return false;
}

function home_onclick()
{ 
    alert("passingRequest");
    createHttpRequest();    
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<br><br>
<form method="get" name="form">
<input type="text" id="query" name="query">
<input type="button" value="Search" id="search" onclick="home_onclick()">
<div></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: SearchService is the servlet which returns the JSON response,We want to access it through request.responseText but the result is not returned in request object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some modification on your code.Hope this will help.

```
function handleSearchResult(){
    if (request.readyState==4 && request.status==200)
    {        
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
}

function createHttpRequest()
{
//....
if(request) {
    request.onreadystatechange = handleSearchResult;
    var q = encodeURI( document.getElementById("query").value );
    request.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/WebSearchOptimization/SearchService?"+q,true);
    request.send(null);
}
//.....
}
```